# List of Apple's reverse geocode countries

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-location, clgeocoder

I'm using Swift to do a reverse geocode on a device's location, getting the country. Then finding the index of that country in an array and scrolling to that index in my `UITableView`.

My problem is, I can't find a list of the country names Apple would return.

For example, my `UITableView` might have a row with the title "United States of America", but the country returned by Apple's API is "United States". My `UITableView` then obviously doesn't scroll to that position.

I've thought of running through the array and doing a type of `contains()` to see if the country returned by Apple is somewhere within the array element but this seems like a pretty nasty way around both for performance and the fact that it will only solve SOME instances of the problem.

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. I haven't looked into it properly but I imagine that they would use some sort of standard country code as well as the name. Is that a possibility?

Comment: I found something where a guy used a python script to convert standard country codes into country names. Codes seem to be standard across the board, but even the names returned by pythons libraries are different and I haven't yet found anything identifying a specific standard of some sort :/

Comment: Use the codes. Not the names :-) if apple decides to change how it returns the name then it will break. But not if you're using he codes.

Comment: You've tagged the question MKReverseGeocoder but since that was deprecated a long time ago, you must be using CLGeocoder instead?  With CLGeocoder, the CLPlacemark has a ISOcountryCode property which is based on a standard.

Comment: Yes I am using CLGeocoder - not sure why I used MKReverseGeocoder... Ok I think I'm going to try link the codes to a list of some sort. I cant let the user select select their country code instead of country name - UX 101 :P

Answer (score 3):

You can find the official list of ISO country codes (which are returned by a reverse geocode) [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1). It is the Alpha-2 code that gets returned.

Comment: Although not exactly what i was looking for - was looking for a list of full country names geocode returns, ISO and alpha-2 codes are 2/3 letter codes) - i can still use this information. Thank you :)

Comment: Does Apple use ```ISO 3166-1```, or do they use some other ISO version? I can't find out which version they support on their developer documentation site.